# find a trend in data set thats shows if the data is changing its overall average value

Tags: sas

I have a data set that has an average value per each week. I also have an overall average for the period that I have my data run for.
I would like to perform a "Control chart" analysis on this data set.

I want to know if 6 consecutive weeks have had their mean value, above the overall mean. So in the example below, I would like my output to say: Week 14.(Date the  mean started changing)

Can you please suggest me an approach that can calculate the "6 consecutive values above overall average value"?

[image]

Comment: This question is more appropriate for CrossValidated. This site is geared towards programming questions related to SAS. If you have tried this in SAS and need help getting your code to work, we can do that.

Comment: Do you have SAS/QC ?

Comment: Please show what code you have tried.  Also, please post your sample data as text (or better yet code for a data step with CARDS statement to make the sample data). This will make it easier for others to help you.  Also, do you want other westgard rules as well (consecutive decreasing, consecutive above or below the mean, etc)?  If you have SAS/QC, you should be able to get what you want from PROC SHEWHART.

Answer (score 0):

If the mean changes, would the new "overall mean" also change as you keep doing comparisons? Putting that aside for the moment, if there was one overall mean and you were trying to detect the first time 6 weeks exceed it:

```
above_avg_counter=0;
if week_value > overall_mean then above_avg_counter+1;
else above_avg_counter=0;
....any other stuff in data step...
if above_avg_counter >= 6 then output;
```

This should show you every week where it is the 6th (or greater) week to exceed the mean.